# Calculating first and last day of month from a yearmon object

Tags: r, xts, zoo, lubridate

I have a simple df with a column of dates in `yearmon` class:

```
df <- structure(list(year_mon = structure(c(2015.58333333333, 2015.66666666667, 
                                  2015.75, 2015.83333333333, 2015.91666666667, 2016, 2016.08333333333, 
                                  2016.16666666667, 2016.25, 2016.33333333333), class = "yearmon")), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                               "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I'd like a simple way, preferably using base R, `lubridate` or `xts` / `zoo` to calculate the first and last days of each month.

I've seen other packages that do this, but I'd like to stick with the aforementioned if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)
df %>% 
   mutate(firstday = day(year_mon), last = day(as.Date(year_mon, frac = 1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base R, you could convert the `yearmon` object to date using `as.Date` which would give you the first day of the month. For the last day, we could increment the date by a month (1/12) and subtract 1 day from it.

```
df$first_day <- as.Date(df$year_mon)
df$last_day <- as.Date(df$year_mon + 1/12) - 1
df  

#   year_mon      first_day  last_day  
#   <S3: yearmon> <date>     <date>    
# 1 Aug 2015      2015-08-01 2015-08-31
# 2 Sep 2015      2015-09-01 2015-09-30
# 3 Oct 2015      2015-10-01 2015-10-31
# 4 Nov 2015      2015-11-01 2015-11-30
# 5 Dec 2015      2015-12-01 2015-12-31
# 6 Jan 2016      2016-01-01 2016-01-31
# 7 Feb 2016      2016-02-01 2016-02-29
# 8 Mar 2016      2016-03-01 2016-03-31
# 9 Apr 2016      2016-04-01 2016-04-30
#10 May 2016      2016-05-01 2016-05-31
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `as.Date.yearmon` from zoo as shown.  `frac` specifies the fractional amount through the month to use so that 0 is beginning of the month and 1 is the end. 
 The default value of `frac` is 0.

You must already be using zoo if you are using `yearmon` (since that is where the `yearmon` methods are defined) so this does not involve using any additional packages beyond what you are already using.

If you are using dplyr, optionally replace `transform` with `mutate`.

```
transform(df, first = as.Date(year_mon), last = as.Date(year_mon, frac = 1))
```

gives:

```
   year_mon      first       last
1  Aug 2015 2015-08-01 2015-08-31
2  Sep 2015 2015-09-01 2015-09-30
3  Oct 2015 2015-10-01 2015-10-31
4  Nov 2015 2015-11-01 2015-11-30
5  Dec 2015 2015-12-01 2015-12-31
6  Jan 2016 2016-01-01 2016-01-31
7  Feb 2016 2016-02-01 2016-02-29
8  Mar 2016 2016-03-01 2016-03-31
9  Apr 2016 2016-04-01 2016-04-30
10 May 2016 2016-05-01 2016-05-31
```